# Can I use a decision tree to compare values for pairs of attributes?

Tags: decision-tree, supervised-learning

I would like to use a decision tree for binary classification. I would like to know if my approach is a valid approach for decision trees.

Each instance in my data set has pairs of attributes, and I have identified that for some pairs, I can compare the values to make a decision. For example, an instance may have the following attributes:

instance = {A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4}

A1 and B1 have different values, but refer to the same feature--this is that I meant when I referred to them as a pair. What I would like to do is have nodes in the tree that compare values of a pair:

```
               (A1 > B1)
               /        \
         (A2 < B2)   (A3 > B3)
         /       \   /       \
                  ...
```

**Is this a valid approach using decision trees?**

**Is there a better learning approach for this type of problem?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid approach indeed. All you need is to create new binary features like

```
C[i] = 1 if A[i] > B[i] else 0
```

or just

```
C[i] = A[i] - B[i]
```

and feed them to an ordinary decision tree algorithm, like `rpart` in R on `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` in Python.